# Need Function to Get First day and last day of current week

Tags: c#, datetime, datetime-format, dayofweek

I have two labels First day and Last day in which I want to update it on button click.

I need Function to Get First day and last day of current date so that I can display it on click of next and previous button.

Here is what I have so far:

```
CultureInfo cultureInfo = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture; 
DayOfWeek firstDay = cultureInfo.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek; 
firstDayInWeek = dayInWeek.Date; 
lastDayInWeek = dayInWeek.Date; 
while (firstDayInWeek.DayOfWeek != firstDay) 
    firstDayInWeek = firstDayInWeek.AddDays(-1);
```

but does not give me the next week after this month.

This is what exactly i'm looking for :

[image]

Any one can help to make this working using a single function.

Comment: Which days of the week do you deem to be the first and last? (Different cultures do different things, in different contexts.)

Comment: What have you tried? Just get the current day of week, and then subtract and add the number of days between today and the first/last day. E.g. if today is Tuesday, subtract 2 to get to Sunday and add 4 to get to Saturday.

Comment: I have used this
 CultureInfo cultureInfo = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
            DayOfWeek firstDay = cultureInfo.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek;
            firstDayInWeek = dayInWeek.Date;
            lastDayInWeek = dayInWeek.Date;
            while (firstDayInWeek.DayOfWeek != firstDay)
                firstDayInWeek = firstDayInWeek.AddDays(-1);

but does not give me the next week after this month

Comment: @Hitesh I've added your code to your question, instead of commenting you can anytime edit your question to add additional infomration. Next time before posting a question make sure that you include all the relevation info: description of your problem, what research you did, what code you have, and what is not working with your current approach.

Answer (score 8):

```
DateTime baseDate = DateTime.Now;
var thisWeekStart = baseDate.AddDays(-(int)baseDate.DayOfWeek);
var thisWeekEnd = thisWeekStart.AddDays(7).AddSeconds(-1);
```

Comment: When I run the following dotnet fiddle the start and end days are both Sundays. If a week starts on a Sunday it should end on a Saturday?
https://dotnetfiddle.net/lFe32N

Answer (score 7):

Try this :

```
private static void GetWeek(DateTime now, CultureInfo cultureInfo, out DateTime begining, out DateTime end)
{
    if (now == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("now");
    if (cultureInfo == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("cultureInfo");

    var firstDayOfWeek = cultureInfo.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek;

    int offset = firstDayOfWeek - now.DayOfWeek;
    if (offset != 1)
    {
        DateTime weekStart = now.AddDays(offset);
        DateTime endOfWeek = weekStart.AddDays(6);
        begining = weekStart;
        end = endOfWeek;
    }
    else
    {
        begining = now.AddDays(-6);
        end = now;
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```
DateTime begining;
DateTime end;

var testDate = new DateTime(2012, 10, 10);
GetWeek(testDate, new CultureInfo("fr-FR"), out begining, out end);
Console.WriteLine("Week {0} - {1}", 
                  begining.ToShortDateString(), 
                  end.ToShortDateString()); // will output Week 10/8/2012 - 10/14/2012
```

Answer (score 0):

So, on a button click, you have a one week period. Lets say that is defined by a starting date. The DateTime structure has a property DayOfWeek that returns an enum like  DayOfWeek.Sunday. So here is a code fragment that may help:

```
var startOfWeek = DateTime(xx, yy ...); // defined by your business code

var firstDayOfWeek = startOfWeek.DayOfWeek;
var lastDayOfWeek = firstDayOfWeek.AddDays(6).DayOfWeek;
```

I have not compiled this code, straight off my head, so hope it is okay.

Comment: I rob i have edited my question with screen. that is what i m looking for t complete my functionality . can you help me for that.